# How to use .appendTo() with a string variable to update DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to use appendTo to update a div with some text.

```
        $('<p>text_info<p>').appendTo('#text_view_div');
```

works as expected

```
        $(text_info).appendTo('#text_view_div');
```

does not. 
JQuery is treating the text_info variable as a jquery type variable and is unable to find the variable (because it does not exist). How do I use a string variable with the appendTo command properly?

Update to add additional code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
var text_info;
$('#information_input').on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        text_info = $('#information_input').val();
        $('#information_input').val('');
        $(text_info).appendTo('#text_view_div');
    }
});
```

});

Comment: what is the content of text_info variable?

Comment: Could you use `append` instead? `$('#text_view_div').append(text_info);` No need to turn the text into a jQuery object...

Comment: Content of the variable is text a user enters.

Comment: It's highly likely that I can use append. I'll attempt that now.

Comment: A.O.'s comment solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct way to achieve this is to use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) rather than [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/):

`$('#text_view_div').append(text_info);`

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a jQuery fragment from a string that is not a valid [htmlString](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString). However, append does let you append text that is not considered an htmlString to an existing jQuery object

```
$('#text_view_div').append('not an htmlString');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString